Can one use "Percentage Used" reliably on Samsung EVO NVMe disks?
There are 2 disks in the server, both are Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB and with 2B2QEXM7 firmware.
# smartctl -A /dev/nvme0
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-187-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x04
Temperature:                        44 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    100%
Data Units Read:                    397,100,009 [203 TB]
Data Units Written:                 720,731,497 [369 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 5,087,298,653
Host Write Commands:                24,700,879,764
Controller Busy Time:               1,679,412,115
Power Cycles:                       12
Power On Hours:                     31,907
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   7
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      51
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               44 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               50 Celsius

# smartctl -A /dev/nvme1
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-187-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        54 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    66%
Data Units Read:                    329,217,687 [168 TB]
Data Units Written:                 528,237,040 [270 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 3,469,100,762
Host Write Commands:                17,644,061,437
Controller Busy Time:               83,471,736
Power Cycles:                       12
Power On Hours:                     31,535
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   7
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      51
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               54 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               62 Celsius

See the first disk has Percentage Used 100%, yet the 2TB version of this disk should have a 1200TBW endurance.
The other disk shows more or less incorrect (?) proportion.
# nvme error-log /dev/nvme0
<skipped>
.................
 Entry[63]   
.................
error_count  : 0
sqid         : 0
cmdid        : 0
status_field : 0(SUCCESS: The command completed successfully)
parm_err_loc : 0
lba          : 0
nsid         : 0
vs           : 0
cs           : 0
.................


Why does it report it like that?
UPD: please don't suggest to replace a drive:

It's a member of distributed replicated network storage
The server is ephemeral - even if all data on it is lost - recovery will take less time than me explaining those suggestions are off-topic here.


I am unaware of the business-related question here. If you want to know how many TBW the drive can withstand, you need to look into the datasheet.

@djdomi I already specified that the datasheet specifies it as 1200TBW. My question is: why the percentage used is 100%? It triggers monitoring, yet I cannot see why.

It depends on how the counter works. If the damage is not significant and the drive feels okay, and it starts counting down instead of up, that could be a reason.

@djdomi "If the damage is not significant" --- that's my question: where I find out why it's now 100%.

One possible reason is that write amplification varies among the drives (due to varying write "pattern" they "experienced").

@TomYan but 370Tb is still very far from 1200Tb? Doesn't it count LBAs, instead of actual bytes?

No idea. Technically the value could go up to 255. Maybe Samsung decided to ignore the NVMe spec and use a "base" larger than 100 to represent the 1200 TBW.

Yes. This means that you should proactively replace the disk.

My question was: "why it reports 100%" while there are NO other signs of wear or errors and while TBW is <30%.

I doubt that you are able to account for every byte written to the device over the previous 3.5 years. The alternative is the device is simply defective and the value is merely a symptom. Time to purchase a replacement $180 drive.

"I doubt that you are able to account for every byte written to the device over the previous 3.5 years" --- it's not me who accounts, it's the SMART stats that accounts LBA written. "and the value is merely a symptom" --- or a firmware bug, that uses 300TBW assumption (from smaller models)?

You should consider tracking information like this over time. And it's common to have multiple thresholds such as "warning" and "error". If you did this, there would be meaningful information. As it stands, the question exists either for confirmation or to identify a rare and special flower.

I'm sorry, but neither your answer as-is, nor these comments are useful: my question is clear - for my very device, how EXACTLY to explain the 100%. I don't need guesses or a suggestion to buy a new drive. If you cannot explain it exactly - could you please remove your answer as it does not address the very question I asked. Thank you!
